# Short date format still has time

Tags: python, date, strptime

I am having date troubles with a python script I am writing. Why is this false? I am not understanding why `00:00:00` is still present even though I have explicitly requested only the day, month, year?

```
date1 = datetime.strptime('22 Dec 2016', '%d %b %Y') <-- 2016-12-12 00:00:00
date2 = datetime.today().date()
print(date1==date2)  # False
```

Comment: Why would a datetime object be equal to a date object?

Comment: string != date so its False

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi: not a string, a `datetime` object.

Comment: I understand that a string is not a datetime object but it is the format I am given, the date is hardcoded at the moment. All I am trying to do is check that a date in that format ('%d %b %Y') is equal to todays date.

Comment: @morganAbbotts: `datetime.strptime()` always produces a `datetime` instance; any parts not present in the string get a default value, see the documentation. If you don't have any time components in the parse result, the time is set to 00:00:00, but that's still a time component!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing a `datetime` object and a `date` object; `datetime.strptime()` *always* produces a `datetime` instance; even though the time is set to midnight, that's *still* a date and time combination.

To compare only *dates*, you need to do so explicitly.

Either:

```
date1.date() == date2  # extract the date, compare to the other date
```

or

```
from datetime import time

# compare the datetime to another datetime with midnight
date1 == datetime.combine(date2, time.min)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing that up, it does make sense now.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you are checking it in wrong direction. Here comparison takes place between datetime and date. Compare date with date then it provide **TRUE**. **00:00:00** Still present as datetime always have time associated with it, so here it is keeping **00:00:00** as no time provided.

```
date1 = datetime.strptime('22 Dec 2016', '%d %b %Y') <-- 2016-12-12 00:00:00
date2 = datetime.today().date()
print(date1==date2)
False



print(date1.date()==date2)
True
```